# How can I transfer ETH from one Poloniex account to another?

Tags: ether, poloniex

I apologize for the newbie question, but I want to send ETH from my Poloniex account to someone else's. Is it possible to do this directly from my Poloniex account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible:

- In your first account (from where you are sending), go to https://poloniex.com/balances, find ETH, click Withdraw.
- Open your second account in a different browser, go to https://poloniex.com/balances, find ETH, click Deposit. Check the Deposit address and save it.
- Go back to your first account, insert the deposit address from the second account.

You should try transferring a small amount first to check if it works.

Comment: I did this, and I can track the withdrawal in the first account, but I can't see the deposit on the second one.

Comment: Can you check the transaction ID of the withdrawal here: https://poloniex.com/depositHistory , then go to https://etherscan.io/tx/YOURTRANSACTIONID . Is it showing up there? It might still be pending?

Comment: Yes, it's showing up there, but still nothing on the second account.

Comment: They must be waiting for a set number of confirmations then. They are known to be slow with that: https://bitsharestalk.org/index.php?topic=7503.0 . Contact their support if the coins are missing: https://poloniex.freshdesk.com/support/home

Comment: I'll wait a bit more and if nothing happens, I'll contact them... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

***Note:***

Just in case someone else is not seeing a record of their transaction, here's the reply I received from Poloniex's support:

> The minimum amount of ETH that can be deposited here before it shows
>   in your account is 1. The next time you will deposit ETH and the sum
>   of the two deposits is bigger then 1, the total amount including your
>   last deposit will be credited.